# Pin correct Annotation Image parse backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have setup a map in which data is loaded from the parse backend. In map I want to display the images that are already saved in Assets folder. Image should be equal to Player Name . There latitude and longitude is already saved in the Parse.

The position of the player is displayed correctly but the image is not being showed correctly , if the last name in the playerName column is Sachin then the image is same for all the player annotation pin.

I want to apply like if playerName == annotation.title the image of rahul should be displayed .

Console Print :

26.6481591686873 , 77.1777485870544 Sachin

27.655116868732 , 77.17778705437 Rahul

28.6479996556687 , 77.1779252453013 Matt

28.6480628887157 , 77.1779590059193 Virat

28.1578689896 , 76.989079 Sachin

```
var playerName:String! 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) in

            if error == nil {
                let myPosts = posts! as [PFObject]
                for posts in myPosts {
                    let latitude12 = posts["playerLat"] as! Double
                    let longitude12 = posts["playerLong"] as! Double
                    let playName = posts["playerName"] as! String
                    self.playerName = posts["playerName"] as! String

                    print(latitude12,"," , longitude12, playerName)
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    //let customAnno = MKAnnotationView()

                    let locationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude12, longitude12)
                    annotation.coordinate = locationCoordinate
                    //customAnno.enabled = true
                    let anno = self.mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("places")
                    if anno == nil {

                        // if annotation.title == "Sachin" {
                        //}
                        annotation.title = playerName
                        self.mapView.addAnnotations([annotation])

                    } else {
                        anno?.annotation = annotation
                    }
                }
            }
        }

 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let identifier = "customAnnotationView"
    let annotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()

    // custom image annotation
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
    }

        if annotation1.title == "Rahul" {
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "Rahul")}
        else if annotation1.title == "Sachin"{

     annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "Sachin")
        }
    return annotationView


}
```

I have tried all codes but the image is same for all the players image.

Comment: Did you check that your image name is sachin (all lowercase). Please check because the image named are case sensitive. Also where those images are located in your image assets or  inside another folder in your project?

Comment: I tallied name (sachin) saved as sachin.png I have tried both the ways with sachin & sachin.png , but all the pin annotation have same image that is of sachin

Comment: And the image that you want to display is the image of the player name? so it can be "scahin" or "ran" or "sabhay" ?

Comment: right but in case of rahul i have saved as Rahul.png so therefore I have typed it as UIImage(named:"Rahul")

Comment: And let's assume that it is Rahul.. do you see the image of it or you also have an issues with displaying the annotation view image?

Comment: All the pin annotations have same image i have changed at backend and changed the last value of playerName to Rahul and the image of Rahul start appearing on all pin annotations

Comment: So i guess you have an issue with reusing the annotation in the map. Can you please check if this is the case?